# foreach in PHP+MySql that repeats itself more than 10 times

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

Here's the code:

```
<?php
/*try catch PDO*/
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM eleves');
?>
<ul> 
<?php 
    while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
        foreach ($donnees as $student){ 
            $name=$donnees["nom"];
            $surname=$donnees["prenom"]?>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <?= $surname;
            echo $name ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Database is a list of +-30 people including these columns:

```
id    nom    prenom    photo    description

1    name1    surname1    photo1    description1
2    name2    surname2    photo2    description2

etc...
```

i'm trying to display a list of each people's name and surname once but it dis plays the list around 10 times or more each name

```
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name1 surname1
name2 surname2
name2 surname2
name2 surname2
name2 surname2
...

instead of:

name1 surname1
name2 surname2
name3 surname3
.......
```

As a beginner in PHP, i'm wondeing why and how to precize that the items are supposed to nbe displayed once

Comment: You do not need the `foreach ($donnees as $student){ ` loop as well as the `while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, you have a nice question and good to see that you are trying PDO.

Actually you don't need to use the foreach loop after fetching the rows by while loop.

Just use-

```
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo $donnees['nom'] . '  ' . $donnees['prenom'] . '<br/>';
}
```